# How can I solve this error in my Laravel model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's my code.
The database name is socapa.

```
class Student extends Model
{
...
public static function rsStuds( 
        $varSession_rsStuds,
        $varCampus_rsStuds,
        $varProgram_rsStuds,
        $varSeason_rsStuds,
        $startRow_rsStuds,
        $maxRows_rsStuds) {
        return Student::select(
                    'contacts.FirstName',
                    'contacts.LastName',
                    'contacts.ContactID',
                    'students.StudentID',
                    'registrations.CourseID',
                    'registrations.RegDate', 
                    'contacts.City',
                    'contacts.State', 
                    'contacts.Country', 
                    'campuses.CampusName', 
                    'programs.ProgramName', 
                    'courses.SessionID', 
                    'courses.CourseName', 
                    'courses.Season', 
                    'students.StudentID',
                    'programs.ProgramID', 
                    'sessions.SessionID',
                    'sessions.SessionName',
                    'programs.ProgramName')
                ->join('registrations', 'students.StudentID', '=', 'registrations.StudentID')
                ->join('contacts', 'contacts.ContactID', '=', 'students.StudentContactID')
                ->join('courses', 'courses.CourseID','=', 'registrations.CourseID')
                ->join('campuses', 'campuses.CampusID', '=', 'courses.CampusID')
                ->join('programs', 'programs.ProgramID', '=', 'courses.ProgramID')
                ->join('sessions', 'sessions.SessionID', '=', 'courses.SessionID')
                ->where('courses.SessionID', 'LIKE', "%".$varSession_rsStuds."%")
                ->where('courses.CampusID', 'LIKE', "%".$varCampus_rsStuds."%")
                ->where('courses.ProgramID', 'LIKE', "%".$varProgram_rsStuds."%")
                ->where('courses.Season', '=', ''.$varSeason_rsStuds)
                ->groupBy('courses.ProgramID')
                ->orderBy('contacts.LastName')
                ->skip(''.$startRow_rsStuds)
                ->take(''.$maxRows_rsStuds)->get();
    }
...
}
```

When I run the project, the error following bellow, appears.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'socapa.contacts.FirstName' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `contacts`.`FirstName`, `contacts`.`LastName`, `contacts`.`ContactID`, `students`.`StudentID`, `registrations`.`CourseID`, `registrations`.`RegDate`, `contacts`.`City`, `contacts`.`State`, `contacts`.`Country`, `campuses`.`CampusName`, `programs`.`ProgramName`, `courses`.`SessionID`, `courses`.`CourseName`, `courses`.`Season`, `students`.`StudentID`, `programs`.`ProgramID`, `sessions`.`SessionID`, `sessions`.`SessionName`, `programs`.`ProgramName` from `students` inner join `registrations` on `students`.`StudentID` = `registrations`.`StudentID` inner join `contacts` on `contacts`.`ContactID` = `students`.`StudentContactID` inner join `courses` on `courses`.`CourseID` = `registrations`.`CourseID` inner join `campuses` on `campuses`.`CampusID` = `courses`.`CampusID` inner join `programs` on `programs`.`ProgramID` = `courses`.`ProgramID` inner join `sessions` on `sessions`.`SessionID` = `courses`.`SessionID` where `courses`.`SessionID` LIKE %1% and `courses`.`CampusID` LIKE %1% and `courses`.`ProgramID` LIKE %1% and `courses`.`Season` = -1 group by `courses`.`ProgramID` order by `contacts`.`LastName` asc limit 50 offset 0)

Comment: That's because of [sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting.. non-aggregated columns should all be listed in the `GROUP BY`. Here, [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Why are you using a huge DB query instead of Eloquent relations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `config` folder and open `database.php` find `mysql` and change

```
'strict' => false,
```